# Unable to upload video file

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload a video file with my controller as below

**Controller**

```
if(Request::hasFile('file1')){
    echo "Yes, file";
    exit;    
    $file = Request::file('file1');
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = public_path().'/uploads/';
    return $file->move($path, $filename);
} else {
    echo "No file";
    exit;
}
```

When i submit my  a JPG/PNG file, it echo "Yes, file" i.e the file exist but when i submit an MP4 video, the file isn't found..

What could be the issue please ? Is there a particular way of sending Mp4 to my server in Laravel ?

Comment: you are ```exit``` the file before doing the request file.

Comment: @Vidal he does that to confirm if there is a file or not in the request

Comment: I am referring to this ```echo "Yes, file";
   exit;``` he exit  after the echo...

Comment: @Vidal, I am doing that to confirm if a file exist before i run any other process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here can be your **php configuration** in `php.ini` regarding the max allowed size of the uploaded file.

```
post_max_size 
upload_max_filesize
```